# 321 stainless electrode corrosion factors? (arc erosion resistantance)

Tags: corrosion

I am looking to lengthen the life of 321 stainless Steel electrodes (arcing through quartz glass).

If I seal off the electrodes from oxygen (thermally conductive potting compound) will this increase the high-temp / high-voltage corrosion rate?

I thought keeping out humidity would help long term, (current electrodes are rusted out even though they are stainless), but I read about how the SS metal may need oxygen to heal the surface?